# Matching Column numbers from two different txt file

Tags: bash, awk

I have two text files which are a different size.  The first one  below example1.txt has only one column of numbers:

```
101
102
103
104
111
120
120
125
131
131
131
131
131
131
```

And the Second text file example2.txt has two columns:

```
101     3
102     3
103     3
104     4
104     4
111     5
120     1
120     1
125     2
126     2
127     2
128     2
129     2
130     2
130     2
130     2
131     10
131     10
131     10
131     10
131     10
131     10
132     10
```

The first column in the  example1.txt is a  subset of column one in example2.txt.  The second column numbers in example2.txt are the associated values with the first column.

What I want to do is to get the associated second column of example1.txt following the  example2.txt. I have tried but couldn't figure it out yet. Any suggestions or solutions in bash, awk would be appreciated

Therefore the result would be:

```
101     3
102     3
103     3
104     4
111     5
120     1
120     1
125     2
131     10
131     10
131     10
131     10
131     10
131     10
```

**UPDATE:** 
I have been trying to do the column matching like :

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{c[$1]++;next};c[$1] > 0' example1.txt example2.txt > output.txt
```

In both files, the first column goes like an ascending order, but the frequency of the same numbers may not be the same. For example, the frequency of 104 is one in the example1.txt, but it appeared twice in the example2.txt The important thing is that the associated second column value would be the same for example1.txt too. Just see the expected output in the end.

Comment: Is this a python or awk question? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: @oguzismail, I'm a beginner in awk, and it would be great if I can manage to solve it in awk. I have been trying to match the column matching  like :

`awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{c[$1]++;next};c[$1] > 0' example1.txt  example2.txt > output.txt`

Comment: Is the first column always in the same order in both files? Or does the order of resulting lines matter?

Comment: In both files, the first column goes like an ascending order, but the frequency of the same numbers may not be the same. For example, the frequency of 104 is one in the example1.txt, but it appeared twice in the example2.txt

The important thing is that the associated second column value would be the same for the example1.txt too.  Just see the expected output in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++; next} ($1 in a) && b[$1]++ < a[$1]' f1 f2
101     3
102     3
103     3
104     4
111     5
120     1
120     1
125     2
131     10
131     10
131     10
131     10
131     10
131     10
```

This solution doesn't make use of the fact that the first column is in ascending order. Perhaps some optimization can be done based on that.

`($1 in a) && b[$1]++ < a[$1]` is the main difference from your solution. This checks if the field exists as well as that the count doesn't exceed that of the first file.

Also, not sure why you set the field separator as `|` because there is no such character in the sample given.